# How to use a parameter in WebService and pass it to stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-services

Firstly I'm new to Angular JS and trying to explore the language, So I'm not fluent...:)

I'm trying to do a simple call to a stored procedure from a web service by collecting the data passed from URL. No data is being fetched.

I know I'm messing it up somewhere, can you guys please point me out where. :)

This would be my URL:

```
http://localhost:2752/ProjectName/PageName.aspx?Id=24
```

This is my script where I'm fetching the data from the URL and passing it to the service:

```
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />

window.params = function () {
    var params = {};
    var param_array = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
    for (var i in param_array) {
        x = param_array[i].split('=');
        params[x[0]] = x[1];
    }
    return params;
} ();


var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

app.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('Services/GetCompletePropDetailsService.asmx/GetPropertyDetailsList' ,window.params.Id)
                   .then(function (response) {
                       $scope.PropertyDetailsListitem = response.data;
                   });
});
```

And this is my service:

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetPropertyDetailsList(String submittedData)
{
    List<PreviewDataClass> listPropertyDetails = new List<PreviewDataClass>();

    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBPCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spPreviewDataUserId", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@UserId", submittedData);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(username);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            PreviewDataClass PropertyDetails = new PreviewDataClass();
            PropertyDetails.FullName = Convert.ToString(rdr["FullName"]);                    

            listPropertyDetails.Add(PropertyDetails);
        }
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listPropertyDetails));
}
```

Any better method to achieve the same is appreciated

Comment: What is the error showing in the browser console? Please show the error details for more details.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 errror in concole. "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Better debug into your method that calls the stored procedure and see what exactly the error is. 500 error is just too general and won't provide much useful info for you to troubleshoot. All you know is something wrong happens on the server. In your case, it could be a DB connection problem, ADO.NET SQL exception, Serialisation issue, etc.

Comment: Yea, I'll better do that.. :) ..But can someone confirm if the manner in which the data is being passed and collected correct..

Comment: @woodykiddy Nope its not an issue with the DB connection. When I run a StoredProcedure which doesn't take any parameters the code works fine.